# Right turn signals go faster overtime

Tags: electrical, turn-signal

So, my motorcycle right turn signals go faster overtime (aprox 8s after turning them on). The other side just works without any issues. Both front and rear lights are working. What could it be? Bad wiring? Relay? How would you try to find the defect? I have a multimeter.

It's a Triumph Street Triple R 2013, if that matters.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Swap left and right turn signal bulbs and see if the effect moves with the bulbs. Then swap the timing relays.

Comment: I guess there's only one relay, but great idea to swap the bulbs and also the whole indicator assembly if needed. I'll do it and report back.

Comment: "Both front and rear lights are working." What is their behaviour after 8 seconds?

Comment: @WeatherVane Both stay working, but faster

Comment: That's usually a sign of a faulty lamp, on the right.

Comment: Thanks. I swapped the front assemblies today, but nothing changed. I'll try swaping the back lamps.

Comment: Put a new lamp and now it seems to work! I'll test a little longer, but you should submit this as the answer for getting the points :-)

Comment: So, interesting development: after switching the rear lamps side to side, the problem migrated to the other side. Problem fixed, or so I thought: bought a new lamp and the problem persisted! Then I found a bag with old lamps in my garage, and to my surprise, from the 3 lamps I found one of them fixes the issue (I swapped/tested it several times). It seems the ones that aren't working properly have the right wattage/voltage marked on them (12v/10w), so I'm baffled. Anyway, the problem is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

[This wiring diagram](https://diyrepairmanuals.com/product/2013-triumph-street-triple-triple-r-electrical-wiring-diagram-manual/) shows -

- Indicators - 13,16,45 and 46
- Flasher relay (I believe) - 52
- Indicator switch (I believe) - 43
- Dashboard flasher repeater - 1 and 11

The flasher is common to both directions, so it won’t be that causing the issue.

As suggested in the comments, you could swap the indicators.  If possible, I would start by swapping the connectors which can be seen on the wiring diagram a little further back from the indicators, if they are accessible.

The most likely issue is a bad connection that is getting worse as it heats up.  Maybe cleaning the connections at the bulbs is all that is needed.

The issue could also be with the flasher bulb connection on the dashboard, since this is also in parallel with the flasher lamps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details! "The issue could also be with the flasher bulb connection on the dashboard, since this is also in parallel with the flasher lamps." but then it would cause issues for both sides, wouldn't it? Today I swapped the front assemblies, but the problem persisted. I'll try with the back one. I'm happy that you think that the relay is probably not the culprit, since I tried to disassemble it to check but it is full of resin... More news soon!

Comment: This schematic has 2 lamps on the dash, numbered 1 and 11.  Does yours only have 1 lamp?

Comment: you're totally right - there are independent lights on the dash. My mistake

Comment: So, interesting development: after switching the rear lamps side to side, the problem migrated to the other side. Problem fixed, or so I thought: bought a new lamp and the problem persisted! Then I found a bag with old lamps in my garage, and to my surprise, from the 3 lamps I found one of them fixes the issue (I swapped/tested it several times). It seems the ones that aren't working properly have the right wattage/voltage marked on them (12v/10w), so I'm baffled. Anyway, the problem is fixed!